# Context free grammar for a language that is a complement of another

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

> Create a context free grammar for L.
> $$ L=\{a^nb^mc^k | n+m \neq k\} $$

First I tried to create a CNF for a language that accepts strings in which $n+m = k$. I got this:

$$
S \rightarrow aAc
$$
$$
A \rightarrow aAc \mid B
$$
$$
B \rightarrow bBc \mid \epsilon
$$
to create a CNF for $L$, I wanted to add a new start state that basically adds another symbol to the strings accepted by the CNF above. I can add as and cs with no problem but don't know how to add bs since b is in the middle.

Comment: You're very close — I suggest spending more time on the problem.

Comment: Hint: to add b's, you just need to change the last production slightly (and add other non-terminal symbols accordingly)

Answer (score 6):

I would like to add that the language $L_0=\{a^n b^m c^k\;|\;n+m=k\}$ is the deterministic context-free language, and a DPDA can be constructed recognizing $L_0$ by the final state. Then we can use the closure property of DCFLs under the complement and obtain a DPDA for $L$ swapping the final and non-final states in the initial DPDA (with a little mess with the trap state).

The main construction is rather straightforward, but it is refined in the two following aspects:

1. The new stack symbol $A$ is introduced, marking the very first occurrence of either $a$ or (if $a$ block is empty) $b$. If we use the single stack symbol $B$, then we would also have a DPDA (having an $\epsilon$-transition to the state $Q_4$ by the stack symbol $Z_0$), but that DPDA is not so convenient to construct a complement, since it contains $\varepsilon$-transitions between the final and the non-final state. The DPDA below has no such transitions, distinguishing the last pop operation.
2. We omitted most transitions to the trap state $T$, because these transitions correspond to the words not belonging to the language $a^* b^* c^*$ (and the initial language $L$ is a subset of this regular language, thus these transitions kick from $L$ as well).

[image]
Now simply swap the final and non-final states and get the DPDA for the required language.
[image]
If you like to construct PDAs, this technique works rather well for recognizing complements of the deterministic languages, but since you ask not for a PDA, but for a CFG, you still have to make the PDA$\rightarrow$CFG transition. In the case considered, it is again quite straightforward (and gives almost the same result as the direct CFG construction): all what you need is to consider the stored $A$ and $B$ stack symbols as the nonterminals which derive a single letter $c$ if popped and $\varepsilon$ otherwise.

Btw, the PDAs above allow $n$, $m$, and $k$ to be zeros.

Answer (score 4):

There's no procedure for creating a context-free grammar for the complement of a context-free language, because the complement of a context-free language might not be context-free, and the question of whether a language is context-free is not decidable.

Of course, particular context-free languages (and some languages which are not context-free) do have context-free complements, and this is an example of such a language. Indeed, as [@Tonita](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/126412/tonita) observes in her [excellent answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/150829/4416), $L^C$ is a deterministic context-free grammar, which are closed under complement. So that's not entirely a dead end.

But on the whole, it's rarely helpful to try to start with a grammar for $L$ and transform that into a grammar for $L^C$, since the latter might not even exist, and even if it dies, mechanically generating it could be a lot of work.

Here's another approach which often works for problems like this. When trying to deal with languages whose descriptions involve inequalities, it's often useful to remember that $i\ne j$ is the union of the two predicates $i<j$ and $i>j$, and furthermore that $i>j$ is the same as $\exists k>0 \mid i = j + k$. Finally, $a^{j+k} = a^ja^k$. That should be enough to quickly find the solution.

Comment: Re. “there's no procedure”: this is an informal reason, but as a formal argument it's missing some key parts. It could be the case that context-freeness is decidable on languages that are the complement of a context-free language. There could be a procedure that is guaranteed to produce a CFG if the language is context-free, but might not terminate otherwise. Do you happen to know if those are known to be false?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' That is a good question.  You can ask it as a new question here on cs.se.

Comment: @gilles: you misunderstand my intent. I'm not trying to demonstrate whether $L$ is or is not context-free; it's a given that it is. Anyway, the absence of a closure property proves nothing. All my answer is trying to do is to guide OP in a direction which is often useful for finding CFGs for languages which contain inequalities. As Tonita points out, since $L^C$ is deterministic, there is in fact a procedure. All the sane, I think my way is easier. As for your question about recursive enumeration, that doesn't work in the general case because...

Comment: ... it's also not decidable in general whether a CFG produces a particular language. (It's decidable in specific cases; for example, if the language is finite.) Again, that's an informal statement, but you can find the proof in any introduction to formal language theory.

Comment: But even if it did work, it doesn't seem like the sort of procedure which would be advisable if you ran into this question on an exam  :-)